# Smartphone software-oriented periodical tasks reminder

Tags: android, software-development, time-management, task-management, reminders

Some entities do certain periodical tasks by an organizational regulation or method; I primarily mean to non-automatic and software-development-oriented tasks; a person often needs periodical reminders for such tasks.

There are at least two tasks I have to do `once in X amount of time`:

- The first task is non-automatically checking that the forms in my website works properly (running a set of checks both for the login form and the contact form)
- The second task is non-automatically checking that my Wi-Fi hotspot is password protected (to prevent a case that due to some strange software behavior or even a user-interface mistake a password set in the past was deleted).

Both tasks are very different but both has to do with software and both also has to do with my personal business (in case these two facts make it easier to give an answer). I want to remind myself about these two tasks in one Android operated smartphone application that will send me a reminder each, say, four months, to do these two tasks; a large message on my smartphone screen to do just do it.

Comment: what's wrong with a simple [calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.fjsoft.myphoneexplorer.client)?

Comment: Even your default calendar in android can be used too, with reminders on your screen.